# Selecting only the bottle's INSIDE bottom face, to form upward creating a 'hill' of glass in the bottom

Tags: modeling

Looking at the picture I added to model by, you can see the bottle has a "hill" of glass in the bottom. My question is how do I 'get inside' the bottle to select only the inside bottom's top face to form upward, thereby creating a hill? Currently I have a solidify modifier added (but not applied).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blender allows you to hide vertices for convenience in Edit Mode**

Apply the Solidify modifier.

In edit mode select the vertices you do not want to edit.
Hide those vertices.  Edit the visible vertices.

[image]

Alternative.
Change to wireframe mode.  Edit mode. Select the top of the hill vertex which you can see with difficulty.  Press Control [Numeric Keypad + ] to grow your selection.  Then hide the unselected.

[Control I] can invert your selection.

Comment: The bottom I found is one solid face. And Tris to Quads does not make it into a mesh. How can I make a solid face a mesh object so I can thenproportional pull it upward?

Comment: You could try Alt + P to poke the face, then add a loop cut if needed. (Ctrl + R)

Comment: @Marc You can delete the unwanted face in center [face only]. Extrude the desired edges and scale as may times as needed.  Extrude a final time and [Merge to Center] to close surface in triangle fan.

Answer (score 1):

After you hide the outside vertices and add the loop cut to the bottom as Atomic suggested select just the middle vertex > enable proportional editing "connected" > choose a type of falloff from the dropdown menu (I used “smooth” in this example). Grab the vertex up > scroll the mouse wheel to determine how many vertices are affected.

[image]

Comment: GREAT answers. Thank You. As an alternative, after I hid the outside bottom face, I selected the inside bottom face, deleted it, selected the loop of edges, and did a Grid Fill, selected a few center faces and then pulled upward using "O" with the proportional Smooth Falloff.